# Git: How to get the branch name when checked out by revision

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a workspace that is checked out by revision like (because this is how Jenkins checks things out):

```
git checkout -f 3af3d7814aed052f7c250d5a7164eaf1d1b7b3b0
```

How do I figure out the branch name that contains the commit? Since I'm using Jenkins and the VM could be Windows or Linux, I'm looking for a Git only command. If I use `git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD` it returns an exit code of 1.

Comment: You can search the reflogs for the line of the commit...git reflog show --all | grep 3af3d7814aed.. This will indicate which branch the commit was done

Comment: `git branch --contains 3af3d7814aed052f7c250d5a7164eaf1d1b7b3b0` will show you all branches which contain the specified commit. But it will not show you which branch the commit was initially made on. The checkout command you show puts you in 'detached HEAD' state, so it won't show which branch has been logically checked out.